# How to capture a photo from the camera without intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, image-capture

I want my app to be able to capture photos without using another application. The code i used :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = null;
    try
    {
        photo = this.createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
        photo.delete();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But this code uses the phone's main camera app. Can anyone give me some code ?

Answer (score 4):

Taking a picture directly using the `Camera` class is insanely complicated to get right.

I am working on [a library to simplify this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), where you just add a `CameraFragment` to your app for the basic preview UI, and call `takePicture()` on it to take a picture, with various ways to configure the behavior (e.g., where the pictures get saved). However, this library is still a work in progress.

> Can anyone give me some code ?

"Some code" is going to be thousands of lines long (for a complete implementation, including dealing with various device-specific oddities).

You are welcome to read [the Android developer documentation on the subject](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

Comment: I have an app that uses the mediarecorder to record video and its not that big. Isnt there something similar for taking images ? What i want is to get an image and overlay it with another bitmap to create a file.Please check out my full question on this matter  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289544/taking-screenshot-programmatically-doesnt-capture-the-contents-of-surfaceview

Comment: What if i open the camera with camera = Camera.open();  and use Camera.takePicture() as seen on the documentation ?

Comment: @mremremre1: "I have an app that uses the mediarecorder to record video and its not that big" -- then I suspect that you're not handling all the devices. Getting the previews correct alone, for portrait/landscape plus rear-facing/FFC, takes a lot. "What if i open the camera with camera = Camera.open(); and use Camera.takePicture() as seen on the documentation ?" -- that's certainly the starting point.

Comment: Thanks i ll try it. Did you see the other question ? Because if there is a way to get a screenshot directly from the surfaceView i wont have to use the camera api

Comment: @mremremre1: AFAIK, you cannot take a screenshot of a `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Damn. Then i ll try taking a photo and overlaying it with a screenshot of the layout xml.

Comment: @mremremre1: If your app is only for API Level 14+, you could see if `TextureView` lets you take screenshots (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), though I suspect that this will not work either.

Comment: @CommonsWare any library is there to capture image in background without preiview..??

Answer (score 1):

once you have the camera preview set, you need to do the following...

```
protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 0; 

public void capture(View v)
{   
    PictureCallback pictureCB = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
          File picFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
          if (picFile == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't create media file; check storage permissions?");
            return;
          }

          try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "I/O error writing file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
          }
        }
      };
      camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCB);
}
```

And the  getOutputMediaFile function:

```
private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) 
{
      File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());
      if (!dir.exists()) 
      {
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) 
        {
          Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
          return null;
        }
      }
      String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.UK).format(new Date());
      if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) 
      {
        return new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
      } 
      else 
      {
        return null;
      }
}
```

**And you are done!!!**

found it [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/726597-how-to-call-the-camera-in-android-part-2-capture-and-store-photos)

Comment: Thank God for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Camera was deprecated in API 21, the new way is the use [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary).

> To enumerate, query, and open available camera devices, obtain a [CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager) instance.

**To quickly summarize:**

1. Obtain a camera manager instance by calling `Context.getSystemService(String)`
2. Get a `string[]` of device camera IDs by calling `CameraManager.GetCameraIdList()`.
3. Call CameraManager.OpenCamera(...) with the desired camera ID from the previous step.

Once the camera is opened, the callback provided in OpenCamera(...) will be called.