# How to take a photo in your own view for an android app?

Tags: android, android-camera, photo, android-camera-intent

so below is the activity I am attempting to build.

Below, you see an imageview of a house and a lake. When the user enters the activity, a camera will be opened inside a view (in this case, the view is the house and lake) and then the user will press the camera icon to take the picture. How do i go about doing that? I can't find an example online.

Hope you guys can provide an example or point me to a good documented source.

cheers!

[image]

Comment: **"camera will open up in the view that has the house with the lake"**  , It's not clear to me .

Comment: Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Comment: So when the user enters this activity, in a view (in this case the view is the one with the picture of the house and the lake) a camera is open. The user then presses the camera icon below to take the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Short: **NO**, you don't have the skills for that.

Longer: Every device maker also makes the camera app that comes with the device, it handles the inner workings / hardware stuff. Unless you want to deal with the (huge number) of device types, just use the Intent & Camera App already there. No need to get grey hairs over this. It can be done, WhatsApp does it, but there is a lot of brain power to get it done on their side.

What you **CAN** do is using the Intent and receive for a camera app. [Like so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

To get an idea how hard it probably is: [Capture Photo without Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291630/how-to-capture-a-photo-from-the-camera-without-intent)