# screen shot of surfaceView in android

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview

In my application I am having two buttons and a surfaceview for the front facing camera.

When I start the application I can see the camera preview in the surfaceview but when my app takes screenshot of the activity its black in the portion where the surfaceview is.

so the screenshot I took is not capturing the surfaceview, and I need to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any substitute that  you can suggest regard to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289544/taking-screenshot-programmatically-doesnt-capture-the-contents-of-surfaceview?rq=1

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197079/1748764

Comment: One of those comment links should help.  You can't read the contents of the SurfaceView, so you need to "draw" it somewhere else.  Either by actually drawing it to a Bitmap, or by capturing the camera to a buffer (or SurfaceTexture) rather than sending it to a SurfaceView surface.

Comment: thanks I will try the solutions.