# Android picture capture from surfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, local-storage

i am try to to capture image,which previews in a surfaceview and there is a button by which picture taken and save onto memory card.preview and capture works well but not able to store on memory card..
there are created file but picture not store one by one...
plz help me...
my try one is here....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count=0;

     Camera mCamera;
    private CameraView cameraview;
    RelativeLayout mainlayout;
    ImageView capture;
    ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cameraview = new CameraView(this, CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        mainlayout.addView(cameraview);
        capture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capture);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/"; 
            File newdir = new File(dir); 
            newdir.mkdirs();


        capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                  //  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

                cameraview.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                           jpegCallback);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Captured", 2000).show();

            }
        });
    }



    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
             // Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
  };

  /** Handles data for raw picture */
  PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
              //Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
  };

  /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
  PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
              FileOutputStream outStream = null;
              try {

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                                "/sdcard/Demo%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();

              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }

        }
  };



}
```

and my CameraView class is here..

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    int mCameraFacingInfo;
    Context m_context;


    public CameraView(Context context, int camereface) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        m_context = context;
        mCameraFacingInfo = camereface;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCamera != null) {

            int rotation = ((Activity) m_context).getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                    || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {

                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {

                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {

                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            // mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /*mCamera.setCameraViewDisplay(holder);

        mCamera.setCameraViewCallback(new CameraViewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                //
                CameraView.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
*/
        // //////////////////////////////////////////
        synchronized (this) {
            int cameraFacingInfo = -1;
            boolean errorFound = false;

            boolean hasFeatCamera = m_context.getPackageManager()
                    .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);

            if (hasFeatCamera) {

                try {

                    cameraFacingInfo = mCameraFacingInfo;
                    mCamera = Camera.open(cameraFacingInfo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mCamera = Camera.open(0);
                }

            } else if (CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT > -1) {

                try {
                    cameraFacingInfo = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                    mCamera = Camera.open(cameraFacingInfo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errorFound = true;

                }

                if (errorFound == true) {
                    try {
                        mCamera = Camera.open(0);
                        cameraFacingInfo = 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        cameraFacingInfo = -1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (cameraFacingInfo < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(m_context, "No camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            if (mCamera != null) {
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                    int rotation = ((Activity) m_context).getWindowManager()
                            .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "0");
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "90");
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "270");
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                    }

                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                    // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void setCameraFacingInfo(int cameraFacingInfo) {
        mCameraFacingInfo = cameraFacingInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289544/taking-screenshot-programmatically-doesnt-capture-the-contents-of-surfaceview?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342380/screen-shot-of-surfaceview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your jpegCallback class to this:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    //Creating empty file in sdcard
    File pictureFile = new File(String.format("/sdcard/Demo%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.e("IMAGE CAPTURE", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
        return;
    }

    if (data != null) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int memoryLimit = 100;
        if (activityManager != null) {
            memoryLimit = activityManager.getMemoryClass();
        }

        // Considering memory limitation of device we will resize image to prevent OutOfMemory
        if (memoryLimit < 20) {
            opts.inSampleSize = 6;
        } else if (memoryLimit < 40) {
            opts.inSampleSize = 4;
        } else if (memoryLimit < 64) {
            opts.inSampleSize = 2;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
                fos.close();
            }
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what is inside data variable. Did you get any errors?
Just for debug you can remove part with memoryLimit.

Comment: E/Data(4867): [B@4226a6f8

Comment: As I understand jpg file was created but it is empty? Check with debuger every step, especially this line  
if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
  
Code is ok and it should save bitmap to file.