# How to render the view from the opened hardware.camera2 camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I want to display what Android camera films on the `mCameraView`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

    openCamera();
}
```

The following code opens the camera:

```
void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(
                            Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, new StateCallback() {
            .... // Other override methods

            @Override
            public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                // What to type here???
            }

        }, new Handler(cameraThread));

    } catch (SecurityException | CameraAccessException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

How to put what `CameraDevice` displays into the `mCameraView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a surfaceview to display the data. Check the answer here to see how the surfaceview works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299259/2363425