# How can a device take a screenshot while Using the camera? We are unable to capture a surfaceview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to take a screenshot while using the camera, but it's not happening.
I Searched a lot to find out a solution, but none of the answers gave me exact solution.

My Question is: how can a real Android device (any brand and any model) take a screenshot while using the camera if we're unable to capture a surfaceview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture the android device screen content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you can't. The SurfaceView associated to the camera is hardware accelerated so it won't show in your screenshot.

The only solution I came across is to get the preview from the camera and paint it in the SurfaceView programmatically as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289544/taking-screenshot-programmatically-doesnt-capture-the-contents-of-surfaceview/18299259#18299259). Then the screenshot will work.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on it and I will let you know @ rutvik Bhatt